# Google error on redirection from an Nginx proxy pass

Tags: nginx, ionic-framework, google-oauth, ionic-react

I know the title seems confusing but here is the problem.

I have an Ionic React Project and a WordPress site (lets say abc.com ) on an Ubuntu 18.04 server and I want that everybody who visits abc.com/app to be taken to the Ionic web app and for this I have created an Nginx proxy_pass which redirects to the app hosted on S3.

Nginx location block code is below

```
location ^~ /app {
    proxy_pass 'http://abc-20226202347-hostingbucket-dev.s3-website.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/';
}
```

Now when this redirects to the s3 website I get Google Authentication gapi error ( Paused on exception ).

I have already done below things :

- I have already added both the domains in the Project > Credentials > Web Client > Authorized JavaScript origins
- I have also done domain verification for both the domains.

Please Note : WordPress standalone is working properly.

Please lemme know if you need any additional information.

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting?